# PHP link to include header

Tags: php, html

I have  php reading a text file that contains all the names of images in a directory, it then strips the file extension and displays the file name without the  .jpg extension as a link to let the user click on then name, what I am looking for is a easy way to have the link that is clicked be transferred to a variable or find a easier solution so the link once it is clicks opens a page that contains the default header and the image they selected without making hundreds of HTML files for each image in the directory.
my code is below I am a newbie at PHP so forgive my lack of knowledge.

thank you in advance. also I would like a apple device to read this so I want to say away from java script.

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>Pictures</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
    <?php

// create an array to set page-level variables
$page = array();

$page['title'] = ' PHP';

/* once the file is imported, the variables set above will become available to it */

// include the page header

include('header.php');

?>
<center>


      <?php
      // loads page links
 $x="0";

// readfile

// set file to read


$file = '\filelist.txt' or die('Could not open file!');

// read file into array

$data = file($file) or die('Could not read file!');

// loop through array and print each line

foreach ($data as $line) {

$page[$x]=$line;     
    $x++;

}

$x--;

for ($i = 0; $i <= $x; $i++)
 {
$str=strlen($page[$i]);
$str=bcsub($str,6);
$strr=substr($page[$i],0,$str);
$link[$i]=  "<a href=".$page[$i]."jpg>".$strr."</a>";

echo  "<td>".$link[$i]."<br/"; 

}

      ?>
      </P></center>
      <?php

// include the page footer

include('/footer.php');

?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not just link to 'file.jpg' the browser will display that.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a .txt file instead of a database?

Comment: For one thing, unless you're on a Windows server, this `$file = '\filelist.txt'` should be either changed to `$file = '/filelist.txt'` if your file is in the root of your server, or `$file = 'filelist.txt'` if in the same folder as your running code. There are a few other ways of doing this, but you get the idea.

Comment: The txt file is so when a person adds a photo in the directory a script runs on the server to update the txt file then the PHP only reads the txt file so only the jpg pictures are listed in the page the php builds, I will add this is used on a 3rd party app that only display one html page and there are no build in back buttons so the header file contains the menu.

Comment: Fred-ii $file = I striped out the long url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the filename to the url that you want to use as a landing page, and catch it using $_GET to build the link.

```
<a href='landingpage.php?file=<?php echo $filename; ?>'><?php echo $filename; ?></a>
```

Then for the image link on the landing page

```
<img src='path/to/file/<?php echo $_GET['file'] ?>.jpg' />
```

Comment: Since he is new to PHP I will note that this is called a "sticky page" and is a good methodology for this project.

Comment: I think I understand- I will try to do this later today and see how it works I assume the landingpage.php would contain my header.php and footer.php.

Comment: @mjayt I get  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' - for what ever reason I get the get command.

Comment: @mjayt I get a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' - for what ever reason I dont understand the building the href for this. In my code $page[$i]= the link  $strr = is the text displayed on the web page if my picture is @ http://192.168.0.1/auto/IMG_4492.JPG but to keep it simple would the link look like this <a href='landingpage.php?file=<?$http://192.168.0.1/auto/cover4492.JPG=<cover4492?></a>   sorry I if I am totally missing it here. if I understand what the end looks like I can modify my code to the right syntax.

Comment: Okay, so if $page[$i] just contains the filename (i.e. picture.jpg) you could use <a href='landingpage.php?file=<?php echo $page[$i]; ?>'><?php echo $strr; ?></a> which should output something like <a href='landingpage.php?file=picture.jpg'>picture.jpg</a> All you're really doing is creating a link to a new page with the photo name appended to the url. On the landing page, you would use $_GET to grab the filename, then build the src for the image using the path to the file and appending the file name to the end of it.